# Unable to render Shiny-UI layout with navbarPage() and tabsetPanel()

Tags: r, shiny

I am using `fluidPage()`, `navbarPage()` and `tabsetPanel()` together as I wish to switch between tabs. When running the `ShinyApp` I see a **dark boxed area** near the title on the navigation bar. However, when I don't use `tabsetPanel()` I don't see this, as all the tabs go onto navigation bar. How should I remove this **dark box area**?

Error in the UI

[image: error]

Code:

```
# Loading Libraries
library("shiny")
library("shinythemes")

Main_UI <- shinyUI({
  fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
            navbarPage(title="Title",
                       tabsetPanel(id = "inTabset",
                                   tabPanel("Tab1", value = "Tab1", actionButton("b1", label = "Jump To Tab2")),
                                   tabPanel("Tab2", value = "Tab2", actionButton("b2", label = "Jump To tab1")))
            ))})


# Server Function
Main_Server <- function(input,output,session) {
  observeEvent(input$b1, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset", selected = "Tab2")})
  observeEvent(input$b2, {
    updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset", selected = "Tab1")})}

# Run-app
shinyApp( ui = Main_UI,  server = Main_Server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `navbarPage`, you don't need a `tabsetPanel`: the `...` arguments to `navbarPage` should be `tabPanel`s.  The dark blob you see is the tab of the "selected" `tabPanel` in the `navbarPage`: which doesn't exist.

```
Main_UI <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    theme = shinytheme("flatly"),
    navbarPage(
      title="Title",
      tabPanel("Tab1", value = "Tab1"),
      tabPanel("Tab2", value = "Tab2")
    )
  )
)
```

gives you what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the response. My goal is to make connectivity between the tabs with ```actionButton()``` but I am not able to make the connection work without using  ```tabsetPanel(id = "inTabset")```. How should I go about making tab-connectivity with ```navbarPage()```?

Comment: I have edited the code in the post and have included the server function for tab-connectivity

Comment: From the online help for `navbarPage`:  `id` If provided, you can use `input$id` in your server logic to determine which of the current tabs is active. The value will correspond to the value argument that is passed to `tabPanel()`.  It's always a good idea to read the documentation.